# In Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo, what kind of access is User.HasDBAccess referring to?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

[Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.user.hasdbaccess%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) pretty much just says that it returns "a Boolean value that specifies whether the database user has access to the database," but what kind of access is it referring to exactly?  Can the user read/write to the database, or does it just mean that you can simply connect to it?  Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the user can connect to that database, but it doesn't tell you anything about what permissions he has within the database. The documentation for the [equivalent TSQL function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187718.aspx) is very slightly more informative.

Comment: It seems that giving a user Connect permissions is the bare minimum to get HasDBAcess to return true, so yeah it's pretty uninformative in terms of permissions.

Answer (score 0):

It means it can `USE` the database.

Comment: Do you have any documentation that supports this?